# Model whose fields are the result of a calculation on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a practice problem on mongoose.
I have two models, let's call them product and support.
I need to create a third model which is the result of a mathematical calculation between some fields of the first two models (product and support).
However, I don't want this third model to be saved in the database, unless the user wants it.
I would like to have some advice on the best way to do it.

Thanks in advance

as you can see I have two models (product and support) and a third model (calculation) which is the result of a calculation between the first two models.

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    diametre : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['metal', 'wood']
    },
    weight : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    length: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }
})
```

```
const supportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    reference: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    material: {
        type: String,
        enum : ['wood', 'metal']
    },
    internalDiameter : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    externalDiameter : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    internalWidth  : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    externalWidth : {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
    }

})
```

```
const calculSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
    },
    support: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Support',
        required: true
    },
lengthOnSupport:{
 type: Number,
 required: true
},
numberOfSupport: {
type: Number,
required: true
},
    createdAt: {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.now()
    }
})
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you put your code here. With what the code is doing currently and what it is expected to do.

Comment: I edited my post. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect your third model to be used for? Like, there are only product id and support id in the third model.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I have updated the third model and I would like to know what would be the good practice regarding the calculation of the properties lengthOnSupport and numberOfSupport. And how to do it so that I don't have to store them in the database but only at the creation of the model. Thanks in advance